# Trouble with Authenticating with remote EJB calls to Wildfly 10

Tags: jboss, ejb, wildfly-10

I'm trying to do Remote EJB calls to my Wildfly 10/JBoss 7 EAP server, but keep getting Invalid User error messages on my Wildfly server (my EJB is called LoginManager):

```
23:04:02,872 ERROR [org.jboss.as.ejb3.invocation] (default task-6) WFLYEJB0034: EJB Invocation failed on component LoginManager for method public abstract java.lang.String ejbs.LoginManagerRemote.echo(java.lang.String): javax.ejb.EJBAccessException: WFLYSEC0027: Invalid User
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor$1.run(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:69)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor$1.run(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:49)
    at org.jboss.as.ejb3.security.SecurityContextInterceptor.processInvocation(SecurityContextInterceptor.java:97)
```

I've added my user to the application-users.properties file using the add-user.sh/bat scripts.

I've tried putting in breakpoints in the Wildfly server itself in the `SecurityContextInterceptor` class on line 54 and see that the principal is null:

```
                if (holder.skipAuthentication == false) {
                    holder.securityManager.authenticate(holder.runAs, holder.runAsPrincipal, holder.extraRoles);
```

I'm not entirely sure if this `runAs` or `runAsPrincipal` is the principal/credentials passed by the remote EJB invocation, but I suspect it might be responsible for my problem.

I'm calling the remote ejb as:

```
    Properties p = new Properties();
    p.setProperty(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");

    final Context context = new InitialContext(p);
    LoginManagerRemote ejb = (LoginManagerRemote) context.lookup("ejb:ear-1.0/ejbs-1.0//LoginManager!ejbs.LoginManagerRemote");

    return ejb.echo("test");
```

with my jboss-ejb-client.properties as:

```
remote.connectionprovider.create.options.org.xnio.Options.SSL_ENABLED=false

remote.connections=default

remote.connection.default.host=localhost
remote.connection.default.port=8080
remote.connection.default.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOANONYMOUS=false
remote.conncetion.default.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_DISALLOWED_MECHANISMS=JBOSS-LOCAL-USER
remote.connection.default.username=test
remote.connection.default.password=test
```

Am I doing something wrong?  Am I missing something obvious somewhere?  What do I need to do to successfully call a remote EJB?

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

There's a typo in your jboss-ejb-client.properties

remote.conncetion.default.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_DISALLOWED_MECHANISMS=JBOSS-LOCAL-USER

Should be remote.connection.default.connect.options etc etc